# Postgres connection times out on internal network, not external

Tags: postgresql

**SETUP**

Using
`Postgres 11,`
`pg-promise npm module`

I have a local network of about 5 machines all running on a `Class C 192.168.1.0/24` configuration.

My postgres is running on 192.168.1.A and is accessible by external connection through NAT and firewalling and my heroku API connects to postgres on 192.168.1.A perfectly.

On 192.168.1.B inside my network I have the dev version of the API running similarly to heroku, on a different machine.

**The Problem**

192.168.1.B one is persistently giving me a timeout error. The machines are in the same physical location. I'm not sure how to track down why I am getting this timeout error. The setup is very simple.

`pg_hba.conf` has these lines:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

Heroku log says:

```
2021-04-16T22:46:10.973041+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/locations" host=<host> request_id=<id> fwd="<an ip>" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=735ms status=304 bytes=182 protocol=https
```

Express on the local dev machine says:

```
GET /api/locations 500 31647.158 ms - 37
```

I'm stumped as to why this would happen. The WAN connect works, but the LAN connect times out?

SOLUTION

I don't know if I should delete this or not.
The last line was misconfigured.
`192.168.1.0/24` should be `192.168.1.0/32`

Comment: Do the postgres logs show the failed connection attempts?

Comment: No. No connection errors are being logged. There's no connection error to log. It's timing out during the connect. This is the problem. Why would the LAN timeout, but the WAN is a standard 30 -40 ms response?

Comment: @KenIngram Have you checked there is no firewall filtering LAN connections (maybe in the very DB machine)? Firewalls usually operate producing timeouts.

Comment: iptables has no settings on the machine serving postgres.